# An additional resource group, NSG, DNS Zone is created when deploying AKS terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

While creating aks cluster by using terraform and using existing values like resource group, vnet, subnet, network security group,
Deployment creating additional resource group, network security group, dns zone.
Do you have any idea how to stop that or disable?

Creating new RG with name MC_RG_XXXXXXXX

Good things:
Cluster getting created by using existing Vnet, subnet, cluster linked with existing RG but its creating network security Group and DNS Zones with new RG.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is an automatic resource group created to house the cluster https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks , there is an option in preview to specify the name of this resource group using Azure CLI and within an ARM template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-provide-my-own-name-for-the-aks-node-resource-group.

I'm not sure how this will map in Terraform though.